# Pattern Printing in C language

Tags: c

How do we print the following pattern in c language?
There is a square inside another square, which is again inside another square. So, there are three squares in total.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You start with `int main(){`

Comment: Pattern like you want an ASCII drawing?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

**Sample Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_SQUARES  (5)

int main(void) {
   int i,j;

   printf("###########\n");
   printf("#         #\n");
   printf("# ####### #\n");
   printf("# #     # #\n");
   printf("# # ### # #\n");
   printf("# # # # # #\n");
   printf("# # ### # #\n");
   printf("# #     # #\n");
   printf("# ####### #\n");
   printf("#         #\n");
   printf("###########\n");

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
###########
#         #
# ####### #
# #     # #
# # ### # #
# # # # # #
# # ### # #
# #     # #
# ####### #
#         #
###########
```

Comment: That is an amazingly "Dogbert" appropriate answer. Congrats. :)

Comment: @abelenky Thanks! I try to stay "in character". Eh, eh? :)

Comment: @EugeneK I changed my approach mid-way.