# Correct way to free memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management, free

so I'm trying to understand the whole concept of memory management in C and I was given this code:

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[]) {
  item *x = NULL;
  x = (item *) malloc (sizeof(item));

  ...

  free_item(&x);
}

void free_item(item **x) {
  free(*x);
  *x = NULL;
}
```

where `item` is earlier defined structure. The point, where I get confused is `free_item(&x);` because when I write `free_item(x);` and change the function to:

```
void free_item(item *x) {
  free(x);
  x = NULL;
}
```

the code seems to work the same way as the previous one.

So, is there any difference? And if not, is there any reason, why would someone send an adress on a pointer of a structure to a function, which frees this structure?

Comment: Your code does not compile. `void free_item(**x)` is not valid.

Comment: Both methods should free the memory however your second method will fail to set `x` (the local that is in scope within the `main()` function) to NULL, thus hiding the fact that the pointer is no longer valid. That fact is unimportant in this little snippet of code but it does represent a difference which could be important in a real program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. First, I think there's a typo in your modified function. It should be:

```
void free_item(item *x) {
  free(x);
  x = NULL;
}
```

Now, for the differences. The `free` call will succeed, as all it expects is a "pointer-to-type" variable for data which is allocated dynamically on the heap.

The second part, `x = NULL`, will not work as expected. Remember, in C, when passing an argument to a function, we pass by value always, never by reference. You are being passed a **copy** of a variable, so `x = NULL` just sets a temporarily automatically allocated copy of `x` to `NULL`, not the actual variable passed as an argument.

The original function which you changed does both parts correctly.

Comment: @madshogo I realize that. Also, I don't think "simulating pass-by-reference" is a really accurate term. We can't emulate all the features of that like how C++ provides, and we're still just passing a value of type `pointer-to-pointer`. Thank you.

Comment: My apologies, i'm on edge for some reason. And regarding this "simulation" notion, pass-by-pointer is the closest C has to the C++ pass-by-reference, hence the quotes.

Comment: @madshogo No worries :) I'm probably the same, since my response just got instantly downvoted to (-3) with no comments.

Comment: Your function definition has a mistake

Comment: @CoolGuy I think that's because he/she copy-pasted it without looking, that's how it was in the original code iirc

Comment: While your answer is certainly true, is this idiomatic? I would not use a function that takes a pointer to pointer just to do an operation as simple as freeing-and-nulling a ptr. OP's confusion (and a wrong answer) demonstrates that this can be misleading.

Comment: @dureuill Since this code was given to the OP in order to illustrate memory management concepts, I suppose the original intent was not to write idiomatic C code but instead to isolate and put an emphasis on the deallocation instructions.

Comment: @mah From this answer: _The original function which you changed does both parts correctly._

Comment: @madshogo You probably guessed correctly the original intent, but I just find slightly dangerous to use non-idiomatic code to illustrate language concepts. I can see where it's coming from (the author wants to write C that's actually correct) though.

Comment: @dureuill the code (and the structure) will be much more complex, so I will need it to be in a separate function.

Comment: Shouldn't `void free_item(*x) {...` rather be `void free_item(item *x) {...` ?

Comment: Approved of @madshogo 's edits which address the outstanding concerns in the comment thread. Thank you all.

Comment: @Dogbert I sense sarcasm.

Comment: @dureuill Either there's a joke you're referencing which I'm missing, or there's a misunderstanding. I'm almost never sarcastic on SO, save for this one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763849/pattern-printing-in-c-language

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first case, to modify the `content` of pointer variable `x`, you need to pass on using a reference. That's why the `&x` and the double pointer is being used to `free()` the memeory which has been allocated from `main()`. This is correct.
2. in second case, a function-local copy of `x` will be created and passed on to `free_item()` which will have no impact on the `x` present in `main()`. The `x = NULL;` will have the scope only inside `free_item()`.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please point out the error by leaving a comment, so that my mistake can be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are calling `free_item` with argument of type pointer to pointer to item (assuming `item **x` argument).

In second example point value (`main::x`) is copied to `free_item::x` (different scope) and that copied value is set to `NULL` (and value is discarded afterwards).

Add `printf("%p\n", x);` to the end of `main()` (after `free_item`).

With first example you will see `NULL` and with second `x` will still be set to address previously stored there.

In first example, lets say your pointer is on address `0x00400000` and it points to memory allocated at `0x00410000`.

```
0x00400000 0x00410000 <- x is stored here
0x00400004 0x00400000 <- tmp described later; point to x
...
0x00410000 .......... <- x points here; start of item - returned by malloc
```

When you call `item **tmp = &x` you will see that it will contain the address `0x00400000` (and `tmp` itself would be stored on different memory address).

Then in `free_item()`:

```
free(*tmp);     // The same as free(0x00410000)
*tmp = NULL;    // Modifies data at 0x00400000 = NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use free ,you pass the pointer ,not the value of the pointer.

So, if you use

```
 item *x
```

, you should use

```
free(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

1. `x = (item *) malloc (sizeof(item));` is unnecessary. `x = malloc(sizeof(item));` will suffice.

2.

```
void free_item(item *data){
  free(data);
}
```

Is the correct way to do it.

3. Write idiomatic C code. There is no difference perse but its hard do debug and maintain.

I would write   `free_item(x);` rather than `free_item(&x)` and have `free_item(item **x)`

Comment: Since the pointer is passed by value, the `data = NULL;` statement is effectively useless.

Comment: Why would you imply the initial method, passing a pointer to the pointer (and then setting the content to NULL) is invalid? It's a fairly common desire - to set pointers which no longer point to valid memory to NULL.

Comment: Funny how stackoverflow works. Its so cheap to downvote unnecessarily

Comment: Aniket, down votes are people's way of saying "this answer does not address the question and should be deleted". Your post did not address the question; rather you told the OP to do something a particular way in which the OP was already doing -- the OP was asking why one method seems to have different results (when in fact both methods should free the memory while the one you advocate against does more work -- which is appropriate in some circumstances and not something you are right to claim as incorrect). Perhaps that's why you got down voted?